# Join table on XML column with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to join the table `fgz_merken` from the table `fgz_leveranciers`. The table `fgz_merken` has a xml column `lst_leveranciers`. At this moment I only get the record with only one value in the `fgz_merken.lst_leveranciers`. Can you help me?

```
select
  fgz_leveranciers.adres,
  fgz_leveranciers.debiteurnr,
  fgz_leveranciers.fax,
  fgz_leveranciers.fax_jaarbeurs,
  fgz_leveranciers.id,
  fgz_leveranciers.import_leverancier_id,
  fgz_leveranciers.mailto,
  fgz_leveranciers.plaats,
  fgz_leveranciers.plaats_postadres,
  fgz_leveranciers.postadres,
  fgz_leveranciers.postcode,
  fgz_leveranciers.postcode_postadres,
  fgz_leveranciers.stand,
  fgz_leveranciers.tel,
  fgz_leveranciers.tel_jaarbeurs,
  fgz_leveranciers.title,
  fgz_leveranciers.vereniging,
  fgz_leveranciers.website,
  fgz_merken.title as MerkTitel 
from 
  fgz_leveranciers 
  left join fgz_merken on 
    fgz_merken.lst_leveranciers.exist('lst_leveranciers/lst_leveranciers[.=sql:column("fgz_leveranciers.id")]') = 1 
where 
  fgz_leveranciers.id != '0' 
  and fgz_merken.title like '%swa%' 
order by fgz_leveranciers.id
```

This is some data from fgz_merken.lst_leveranciers

```
<lst_leveranciers>
  <lst_leveranciers>
    <value>125</value>
  </lst_leveranciers>
</lst_leveranciers>
<lst_leveranciers>
  <lst_leveranciers>
    <value>16</value>
    <value>40</value>
    <value>269</value>
  </lst_leveranciers>
</lst_leveranciers>
```

Comment: Database is Mssql 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    fgz_leveranciers.*,
    xmldata.i
from
    fgz_leveranciers
    left join
    (                
        Select x.t.value('.','int') i
        from fgz_merken
            cross apply lst_leveranciers.nodes('lst_leveranciers/lst_leveranciers/value') as x(t)
      ) xmldata
    on fgz_leveranciers.i = xmldata.i
```